# How to set `Set-Cookie` header in HttpResponse in Akka Scala?

Tags: scala, cookies, akka, akka-http

I have the following route in my app:

```
val myRoute = Route { context =>

        val handler = Source.single(getRequest(context))
          .via(flow(server, port))
          .runWith(Sink.head).flatMap { r =>

          // Add cookie to response depending on certain preconditions

         context.complete(r)

      }

}
```

My problem is that I can't use the out-of-the-box [`setCookie`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/cookie-directives/setCookie.html) method (or can I?) because I am inside a route, so I will get a type error. I thought about manually adding a header element to the `HttpResponse` (in the example above `r`), but that is quite cumbersome.

Any ideas how I can easily add the `Set-Cookie` header element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setCookie Directive**

A `Route` is just [a type definition](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/index.html#Route=akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]): `(RequestContext) => Future[RouteResult]`.  Therefore you can use function composition to add a cookie to the `HttpResponse` coming from the downstream service.

First create a forwarder that utilizes the predefined flow:

```
val forwardRequest : HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = 
  Source
    .single(_)
    .via(flow(server, port))
    .runWith(Sink.head)
```

Then compose that function with `getRequest` and a converter from `HttpResponse` to `RouteResult`:

```
val queryExternalService : Route = 
  getRequest andThen forwardRequest andThen (_ map RouteResult.Complete)
```

Finally, set the cookie:

```
val httpCookie : HttpCookie = ??? //not specified in question

val myRoute : Route = setCookie(httpCookie)(queryExternalService)
```

**Manual Addendum in Route**

You can manually set the cookie:

```
val updateHeaders : (HttpHeader) => (HttpResponse) => HttpResponse = 
  (newHeader) => 
    (httpResponse) => 
      httpResponse withHeaders {
        Some(httpResponse.headers.indexWhere(_.name equalsIgnoreCase newHeader.name))
          .filter(_ >= 0)
          .map(index => httpResponse.headers updated (index, newHeader) )
          .getOrElse( httpResponse.headers +: newHeader )
      }
...
.runWith(Sink.head).flatMap { response =>
  context complete updateHeaders(httpCookie)(response)
}
```

**Pure Flow**

You can even avoid using Routes altogether by passing a `Flow` to [`HttpExt#bindAndHandle`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/HttpExt.html#bindAndHandle(handler:akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse,Any],interface:String,port:Int,connectionContext:akka.http.scaladsl.ConnectionContext,settings:akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ServerSettings,log:akka.event.LoggingAdapter)(implicitfm:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.Http.ServerBinding]):

```
val myRoute : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = 
  flow(server,port) map updateHeaders(httpCookie)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! In my case manually adding the `Set-Cookie` header was not that easy because I don't want to replace existing `Set-Cookie` data but instead add just my cookie (also I want to preserve all headers). However, I manually implemented it that way with a `RawHeader`.